# How to split/transform a dictionary by keys separated with point in python

Tags: python, algorithm, dictionary

I have a dictionary (or JSON object) that looks like this:

```
{"Key1.Key2.Key3(someparameter)": {"balh.Key1": 4711}}
```

I would like to transform it into a dict that looks like this in python:

```
    {"Key1": 
         {"key2": 
             {"Key3(someparameter)": {"balh": 
                                             {"Key1": 4711}
                                     }
             }
         }
    }
```

My current code, is this, but it doesn't work always:

```
def cleankeys(source) -> dict:
    out = {}
    if source:
        for key, value in source.items():
            newkey = key
            params = ""
            if "(" in key:
                newkey = key.split("(",1)[0]
                params = "("+key.split("(",1)[1]
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                if "." in newkey:
                    rord = newkey.split(".")
                    rord[-1] = rord[-1] + params
                    rord.reverse()
                    tmp = cleankeys(value)
                    for k in rord:
                        tmp = {k: tmp}
                    out[newkey] = tmp
                else:
                    out[newkey] = cleankeys(value)
            elif isinstance(value, list):
                if "." in newkey:
                    rord = newkey.split(".")
                    rord[-1] = rord[-1] + params
                    rord.reverse()
                    tmp = value
                    for k in rord:
                        tmp = {k: tmp}
                    out[k] = tmp[k]
                else:
                    out[newkey] = value
            else:
                print(newkey)
                out[newkey] = value
    return out
```

Can you help me how to do so? Do you have a more efficient way to translate the dict?

Comment: are there always going to be 3 keys or the count could increase/ decrease?

Comment: *It doesn't work always*. Please say *what* doesn't work, what result you get, and why it is unexpected.

Comment: The count of keys and also the deepth can be different.

It failes for example with the following JSON:
{"Key1.Key2.Key3(val.id = obj.id)": {"balh": 4711}}
 ==> Result is {'Key1.Key2.Key3': {'Key1': {'Key2': {'Key3(val.id = obj.id)': {'balh': 4711}}}}} instead of  {'Key1': {'Key2': {'Key3(val.id = obj.id)': {'balh': 4711}}}}

Comment: Debug a failing example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, it's what you need:

```
def convert(data, delimiter="."):
    def split_keys(key, delimiter="."):
        result = []
        start = -1
        key_list = key.split(delimiter)
    
        for i, item in enumerate(key_list):
            if "(" in item and ")" in item:
                result.append(item)
            if "(" in item:
                start = i
            elif ")" in item:
                result.append(".".join(key_list[start:i + 1]))
                start = -1
            elif not item or start != -1:
                continue
            else:
                result.append(item)
        return result

    result = {}

    if not isinstance(data, dict):
        return data

    for key, value in data.items():
        if delimiter in key:
            key_list = split_keys(key, delimiter)
            temp = result

            for i, k in enumerate(key_list):
                if i != len(key_list) - 1:
                    temp[k] = {}
                    temp = temp[k]
                    continue

                if isinstance(value, list):
                    temp[k] = [convert(item) for item in value]
                else:
                    temp[k] = convert(value)

            continue

        if isinstance(value, list):
            result[key] = [convert(item) for item in value]
            continue

        result[key] = convert(value)

    return result


assert convert({"Key1.Key2.Key3(someparameter)": {"balh.Key1": 4711}}) == {'Key1': {'Key2': {'Key3(someparameter)': {
    'balh': {'Key1': 4711}}}}}, convert({"Key1.Key2.Key3(someparameter)": {"balh.Key1": 4711}})
assert convert({"Key1": {"blah": 4711}}) == {"Key1": {"blah": 4711}}, convert({"Key1": {"blah": 4711}})
assert convert({"Key1.Key2.Key3(..x)": [{"blah.Key1": 4711}, {"test2": "respo"}]}) == {"Key1": {"Key2": {"Key3(..x)": [{"blah": {"Key1": 4711}}, {"test2": "respo"}]}}}, convert({"Key1.Key2.Key3(..x)": [{"balh.Key1": 4711}, {"test2": "respo"}]})
assert convert({"Key1.Key2.Key3(someparameter.blah = asdfa.ddd)": {"balh.Key1": 4711}}) == {"Key1": {"Key2": {"Key3(someparameter.blah = asdfa.ddd)": {"balh": {"Key1": 4711}}}}} , convert({"Key1.Key2.Key3(someparameter.blah = asdfa.ddd)": {"balh.Key1": 4711}})
```

Comment: That is almost the correct answer, but it does not iterate over lists

Comment: Hey dukee!Thank you, actually someparameter can include a poin,e .g. {"Key1.Key2.Key3(someparameter.blah=asdfa.ddd)": {"balh.Key1": 4711}}

Comment: @kruemel4 please give in the start post examples for params and lists (input and output structures) and I will update my solution

Comment: Thanks @dukkee. Unfortunately I can't edit the start-post ("Suggested edit queue is full"). I'm very new here, so I started to learn how this works. Some examples are:

-{"Key1.Key2.Key3(someparameter)": {"balh.Key1": 4711}}
-{"Key1.Key2.Key3(someparameter.key = obj.value)": {"balh.Key1": 4711}}

Comment: @kruemel4 I don't see an output state. Use please e.g. https://pastebin.com/ or any other code sharing tool to write examples (important, and output converted state too please) and write here this link

Comment: Hey @dukkee, thank you so much for your support and patience with me. Here the Link to Input-->Output. I think the only thing that makes it a little more complex is, that everything starting from "(" character is something that belongst to the last key.
Pastebin examples are here: https://pastebin.com/WkTdePkk

Comment: @dukkee Thank you very much I'm really thankfull. Unfortunately Test-Case a fails, see the pastebin link:

 {"Key1.Key2.Key3(someparameter.blah = asdfa.ddd)": {"balh.Key1": 4711}} 
--> {"Key1": {"Key2": {"Key3(someparameter.blah = asdfa.ddd)": {"balh": {"Key1": 4711}}}}}

Answer (score 0):

tried with `recursion`. I assume **tuple and sets are not there** in the original data. You can handle them anyway though.

```py
def unpack_str(s, ttype='k'):
    kk = []
    num_bracket = 0
    s_splitted = s.split(".")
    if(len(s_splitted)<2) and (ttype == 'v'):
        return s
    for i in s_splitted:
        if(len(i)>0):
            kk.append(f"<'{i}'")
            num_bracket += 1
    return ":".join(kk) + ':{}' + '>'*num_bracket

def master_unpacker(e, ttype='k'):
    if(type(e) == dict):
        temp = {}
        for k in e:
            kk = master_unpacker(k)
            vv = master_unpacker(e[k], 'v')
            if(type(vv)== str and '<' not in vv):
                hhh = kk.format('"' + vv + '"').replace('<', '{').replace('>', '}')
            else:
                hhh = kk.format(vv).replace('<', '{').replace('>', '}')
                
            temp.update(eval(hhh))
        return temp
            
    if(type(e) == str):
        return unpack_str(e, ttype)
    if(type(e) == list):
        temp = []
        for i in e:
            rr = master_unpacker(i)
            temp.append(rr)
        return temp
    else:
        return e
    
d = {"Key1.Key2.Key3(someparameter)": {"balh.Key1": [{'a1.a2':1, 'b':2}]}}
master_unpacker(d)
```

output

```
{'Key1': {'Key2': {'Key3(someparameter)': {'balh': {'Key1': [{'a1': {'a2': 1},
       'b': 2}]}}}}}
```